# Ubuntu transfer file via Hotspot like with Zapya

Tags: networking, wireless, samba

i have most big file and i'm trying to trasfer that via hotspot like with Zapya, after create new Wireless(shared) on kubuntu and connect to that on kubuntu, i'm connected to that from Windows, now i mist be send file to windows then i'm trying to access windows shared folder via Kubuntu, like with this:

Kubuntu wireless ip is: 10.47.0.1 and after connect to that from windows, windows wireless ip is: 10.47.0.7, now in Kubuntu after type this url:

```
smb://10.47.0.7
```

Konqueror get password from me, my windows username is `pc` and password is `123456` and after type that in get username and password dialog i can not connect to windows shared folders.

who to resolve this problem and connect to windows via hotspot to transfer file?

Answer (score 0):

I did that by installing ftp server app on the phone. launching the app and pressing a simple button gives you an IP and port which you can use through your browser